# UniqueEntity not working - FatalThrowableError in DefaultQuoteStrategy.php line 97

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have `Product.php` entity with self-referencing ManyToMany relationship:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Product")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`Product`")
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"relatedProducts", "productsInRelation"}, message="Product cannot be in relation with itself.")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="productsInRelation")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_related_products",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_source_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_target_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      max = 3,
     *      maxMessage = "You cannot specify more than {{ limit }} related Products"
     * )
     *
     * @var Product[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $relatedProducts;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="relatedProducts")
     *
     * @var Product[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $productsInRelation;

    /**
     * Add relatedProducts.
     *
     * @param Product $relatedProduct
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addRelatedProduct(Product $relatedProduct)
    {
        $this->relatedProducts[] = $relatedProduct;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove relatedProduct.
     *
     * @param Product $relatedProduct
     */
    public function removeRelatedProduct(Product $relatedProduct)
    {
        $this->relatedProducts->removeElement($relatedProduct);
    }

    /**
     * Get relatedProducts.
     *
     * @return Product[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getRelatedProducts()
    {
        return $this->relatedProducts;
    }

    /**
     * Add ProductsInRelation.
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $productsInRelation
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addProductsInRelation(ArrayCollection $productsInRelation)
    {
        $this->productsInRelation[] = $productsInRelation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove ProductsInRelation.
     *
     * @param Product $productsInRelation
     */
    public function removeProductsInRelation(Product $productsInRelation)
    {
        $this->productsInRelation->removeElement($productsInRelation);
    }

    /**
     * Get ProductsInRelation.
     *
     * @return Product[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getProductsInRelation()
    {
        return $this->productsInRelation;
    }
}
```

When I am adding `@UniqueEntity` constraint I am not able to persist the entity because of following error.

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultQuoteStrategy::getJoinTableName() must be
>   of the type array, null given, called in
>   /var/www//vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   on line 1669
>
> 1. in DefaultQuoteStrategy.php line 97
> 2. at DefaultQuoteStrategy->getJoinTableName(null, object(ClassMetadata), object(PostgreSQL92Platform)) in
>      BasicEntityPersister.php line 1669
> 3. at BasicEntityPersister->getSelectConditionStatementColumnSQL('productsInRelation',
>      null) in BasicEntityPersister.php line 1582
> 4. at BasicEntityPersister->getSelectConditionStatementSQL('productsInRelation',
>      object(PersistentCollection), null) in BasicEntityPersister.php line
>      1724
> 5. at BasicEntityPersister->getSelectConditionSQL(array('relatedProducts' =>
>      object(PersistentCollection), 'productsInRelation' =>
>      object(PersistentCollection)), null) in BasicEntityPersister.php line
>      1058
> 6. at BasicEntityPersister->getSelectSQL(array('relatedProducts' => object(PersistentCollection), 'productsInRelation' =>
>      object(PersistentCollection)), null, null, null, null, null) in
>      BasicEntityPersister.php line 882 7 .at
>      BasicEntityPersister->loadAll(array('relatedProducts' =>
>      object(PersistentCollection), 'productsInRelation' =>
>      object(PersistentCollection)), null, null, null) in
>      EntityRepository.php line 181
> 7. at EntityRepository->findBy(array('relatedProducts' => object(PersistentCollection), 'productsInRelation' =>
>      object(PersistentCollection))) in UniqueEntityValidator.php line 117
> 8. at UniqueEntityValidator->validate(object(Collection), object(UniqueEntity)) in RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 852

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"relatedProducts", "productsInRelation"}...
```

This means: make sure that there aren't two entities in my repository with the same `[ relatedProducts, productsInRelation ]` pair. First of all, according to your validation message this is not what you want to do (`message="Product cannot be in relation with itself"`), and second I'm not sure the UniqueEntity constraint can validate such cases.

If you want to use a Symfony constraint, [Expression](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) could be a solution:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this not in this.getRelatedProducts().toArray()",
 *     message="Product cannot be in relation with itself"
 * )
 */
protected $relatedProducts;

/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this not in this.getProductsInRelation().toArray()",
 *     message="Product cannot be in relation with itself"
 * )
 */
protected $productsInRelation;
```

[Callback](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) should work too if you prefer plain old PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution won't work. Symfony form will use getter `getRelatedCollections`, then it will use `add($collection)` method instead of using `addRelatedProduct` accessor.

Comment: I gave you two solutions. What about the first one (`@Assert\Expression`/`@Assert\Callback`)?

Comment: Well, `@Assert\Expression` works perfectly! `@Assert\Callback` should do the job as well. But the example with an exception in `addProductInRelation(Product $product)` will not work.

Comment: OK, I removed the second solution.